# Overriding the user class for symfony 1.4 plugin

Tags: symfony-1.4, session-timeout

Currently, my symfony 1.4 app is using the myUser class. But I need to override the behaviour of this class to work with a single plugin. As it is not the proper way to change the base code, I would like to know whether there is a way to extend the myUser class and use it with my plugin?

What I am trying to achieve is, keeping a separate session timeout for my plugin. In order to do so, I have to separate the http requests of other plugins from the http requests of my plugin. If there is another way of achieving this, it is even better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look to see if there is a myUser.class.php file in the lib folder of your app.  If there isn't create one and in it add:

```
<?php

class myUser extends sfBasicSecurityUser
{
}

?>
```

Or if you are using sfGuardPlugin:

```
<?php

class myUser extends sfGuardSecurityUser
{
}

?>
```

Then clear the cache.

You will be able to use it with your plugin.

As far as the session expiration goes.  It's not clear what kind of information your plugin is managing.  Can't you just expire the information at a certain point?  Symfony allows you to save session data to different namespaces. (The example below uses 'plugin_info'.)  Can't that namespace have an expiration time?

Example:

```
$this->setAttribute('plugin_expiration', time() + 1000, 'plugin_info');

$expiration = $this->getAttribute('plugin-plugin_expiration', time() + 1000, 'plugin_info');

if ($expiration > time())
{
  $this->getAttributeHolder()->removeNamespace('plugin_info');
  // then restart the session here.
}
```

Comment: The issue what I am having is this,
Whenever an http request is sent, the 'last request time' is updated in the myUser class. My plugin makes Ajax requests (http) every 60 seconds. This prevents the entire application from timing-out. I have to avoid this. I need a way to prevent the http requests made by this specific plugin from updating the 'last request time'.